# PHP/MySQL(i) use_result, store_result and MyISAM Table Locks

Tags: php, mysql, performance, myisam

I've read various sources (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716), [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/26/handling-of-big-parts-of-data/), or [this](http://static.nyphp.org/talks/Scaling-Optimizing-Workshop-MySQL-PHP-Connectors-Best-Practices-Performance-Cloud.pdf) one) about the difference between `use_result()` (unbuffered queries) and `store_result()` (buffered queries) and also know that MySQL keeps locks on data (in the case of MyISAM on the entire table) until all the results have been sent to the client.

What I don't understand is why with `use_result()` (unbuffered) queries MySQL keeps locks for a longer time than for `store_result()` (buffered) queries. Why is it so different to use `store_result()` than using `use_result()` and doing the buffering (into a PHP array) myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `store_result()` mysql driver (that is written on lower level than php) is transfers data from server to client and releasing the lock.

When using `use_result()` and buffering in array you need to make a php loop, and because php is an interpreter that loop is slower, so there is a delay between every row fetch.

In order to see this delay measure the time difference taken to execute

```
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {}
```

between `php` and `c`

In general, php code is slower then c code, and php extensions and internal functions are written in c code, so using extension or internal function is always faster than writing the algorithm for that same thing in php code